# How to modify my jQuery script to add a math function and pass the result?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

You can find my jQuery in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qSkZW/9/ where the value changes based on your dropdown selection.

What I need is to multiply the selected quantity with a PHP variable. For example when`$price = '10';` and you select 3 for quantity, you get an output of 30.

Also, how can I pass the result to display it in the next page ?

Thank you.

What I am trying to clone is the **Your Purchase** system found here https://www.groupon.com/deals/pizza-delight/confirmation?ms=false&pledge_id=538463 that you add the quantity and you get the final price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just output the integer directly into the script using php:

```
$("#quantity").change(function () {
    var price = parseInt($(this).val(), 10)*<?php echo $price; ?>
    $("#here").text(price);
}).change();
```

Using PHP 5.4 or short tags enabled:

```
var price = parseInt($(this).val(), 10)*<?=$price?>
```

Comment: The 10 is used with parseInt to specify base 10, otherwise an integer beginning with a 0 will be treated as octal, so `parseInt('014')` gives 12, but `parseInt('014', 10)` gives 14 as expected. It's good practice IMO to always specify the radix with `parseInt`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How to pass the value to the next page? I have to avoid `window.location.href = "newpage.php?price=" + price";` because I don't want it to appear on the url.

Comment: @Nikolai, you shouldn't pass that variable to the PHP page, as that means your user can pass anything to the page (users can send any type of request to your server). Instead you should just pass the quantity along, probably through an HTML `<form>`, and recalculate the price on your server where the user can't change it.

Comment: So you suggest me to make use of jQuery only for viewing purposes right?

Comment: @Nikolai, that's right. Everything in jQuery/Javascript/HTML can easily be modified by the end user, so they can change it to whatever they want. Any calculations you want to trust should be done in server side code, like PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#quantity").change(function () {
     var str = $(this).val();
     $("#here").text(parseInt(str, 10) * <?php echo $price; ?>);
 }).change();
```

[**Your updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qSkZW/6/)

Comment: Thank you for this. How can I save the result to a PHP variable or pass it to the next page?

Comment: The simplest way I can think of would be to redirect the user to the new page, passing it as a param: `window.location.href = "newpage.php?price=" + price";`. You can just add that line of code to the end of your onchange handler. If you want it to pass to your script when the user submits the form, you could either store it in a hidden element or append it to the query string `onsubmit`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to store the php value in a js variable - which you can reference in your js function. Eg...

```
<script>
var price = <?php echo $price ?>;
</script>
```

In addition you can encode php vars as json for easy js access. Eg...

```
<?php

$products = array(
    'Hot socks' => array(
        'price' => 10,
        'description' => 'These socks are steaming HOT!',
    ),
    'Cool socks' => array(
        'price' => 20,
        'description' => 'The perfect treat for for feet on those hot summer days!',
    ),
);

?>

<script>

var products = <?=json_encode($products)?>;

alert('Please buy some hot socks @ ' + products['Hot socks'].price);

</script>
```

edit: example is scarf compatible

Answer (score 0):

You can just echo onto the page in your javascript:

```
<script>
    // some js above here
    php_val=<?php echo $price; ?>
    // some js that uses php_val down here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTML5 custom attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes):

```
<select data-price="10"> ... </select>
```

And then get it with jQuery:

```
 $("#quantity").change(function () {
   var el = $(this);
   var str = el.val() * el.attr('data-price');
    $("#here").text(str);
 })
 .change();
```

Storing it in a `var price` value is not a good solution as it doesn't specify a select element.